# Flash MultiPowUploader - Triggering the Upload Button When Invisible?

Tags: jquery, flash, multifile-uploader

I am using ElementIT's MultiPowUpload v3.3 and I have the standalone, Flash portion working. My problem is when I make the upload button invisible and need to trigger the upload via a standard form element button.

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" action="" method="post">
<select name="menu" MULTIPLE size="2">
<option value="1">some menu item 1</option>
<option value="2">some menu item 2</option>
</select>
<input name="text" type="text" value="some text">
<input type="hidden" name="hdn_frm_submit" id="hdn_frm_submit" value="Upload Files" />
<input type="submit" name="btn_sub" value="Submit Form">

<div id="MultiPowUpload_holder"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Extra/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var params = {  
    BGColor: "#FFFFFF"
};

var attributes = {  
    id: "MultiPowUpload",  
    name: "MultiPowUpload"
};

//MultiPowUpload partameters goes here
var flashvars = {       
  "serialNumber": "MY_SERIAL_NUMBER_INSERTED_HERE",
  "uploadUrl": "insert_the_processing_page_here",
  "formName": "myform",
      "uploadButton.visible": "false",
  "uploadButton.action": "2",
  "useExternalInterface": "true"
};
//Default MultiPowUpload should have minimum width=400 and minimum height=180
swfobject.embedSWF("ElementITMultiPowUpload.swf", "MultiPowUpload_holder", "400", "250", "10.0.0", "Extra/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
</form>
```

I have jQuery available on the page so I will place the Submit button click handler in the doc.ready section. How do I address the Flash uploader's Upload button with jQuery? Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ExternalInterface`
http://www.element-it.com/OnlineHelpMulti/MultiPowUpload_Manual_HTML/tutorial.html#javaScript

probably you are looking for `uploadAll` method
http://www.element-it.com/OnlineHelpMulti/Methods.html#uploadAll

the code you need to add to your sample will be:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#btn_sub").click(function() {
       $("#MultiPowUpload").uploadAll("uploadfiles.aspx");
     });
   });
</script>
```

but you also will need to change the button type from `submit` to `button` to prevent form submitting from html.

```
<input type="button" name="btn_sub" value="Upload Files">
```

i used this docs:
http://api.jquery.com/ready/
http://api.jquery.com/click/
http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Comment: Thx Roman for the response. I have looked through these examples before I posted and because there are not more complete examples, and prob due to my level of JS expertise, I have not been able to code a solution.